# Multiple action for different parts on same armature

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I want to create multiples action for different parts of my model (ex: action only for hand,foot,rest of the body), so I can use different action at same time.
How can I do that in blender?

Comment: with the NLA Editor?

Comment: in the NLA and the action editor.
I want to be able to open and close the hand of my model and at same time do other action with the legs.
Like I want to make a comand for the hand and at same time another comand for the rest of the body.

Comment: what do you mean by "command"?

Comment: An action.Like in NLA where you can choose a set of action for the model to make.

Comment: you're not clear enough about what you want. You can create some specific actions with the Dopesheet (Action Editor mode) and mix them in the NLA Editor. You can also create specific poses with your bones, save them in the Properties > Data > Pose Library, them use them whenever you want. It will really depends on your needs.

Comment: the pose library, can I create a pose only for the bone hands or I have to do all the bones of the model?

Comment: the pose library will only save the pose for the bones you have selected. You have a good tutorial about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FIEzAlnVvw&

Comment: but maybe what you need is to learn how to use the Dopesheet > Action Editor mode and the NLA Editor, because it is really made to mix animations. The Pose Library only save a still pose. PS: well of course if you bring two still poses in the Dopesheet it will interpolate.

Comment: If I can explain better, I would like to make an action of walking and at the same time I want my character to open and close his hand 2 times while walking.

Comment: so you should learn how to create an action (Dopesheet in Action Editor node), then combine them in the NLA editor. You can also create your walking action, duplicate it and just add the open/close hand.